# 'Set-ExecutionPolicy' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file while installing chocolaty

Tags: react-native, chocolatey

'Set-ExecutionPolicy' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. getting this error while trying to install chocolaty through cmd

Answer (score 32):

`Set-ExecutionPolicy` is a PowerShell Cmdlet.
You should run it in a PowerShell (Admin-) Session, not in cmd.

Take a look at the installation instructions from chocolatey.org. Official chocolatey documentations is pretty good, as I think:

https://chocolatey.org/install#individual

Comment: this is the correct command sequence under this link: https://chocolatey.org/docs/installation
@"%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoProfile -InputFormat None -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = 3072; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))" && SET "PATH=%PATH%;%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\chocolatey\bin"

Answer (score 1):

'Set-ExecutionPolicy' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file while installing chocolaty
for this question I think you are using command prompt but Set-ExecutionPolicy is a command only for powershell.

Answer (score 1):

Just right click on "powershell" then choose "run as adminstrator"

Answer (score 0):

Dont choose command prompt instead of power shell we think that both are same but its not
Search
Window power shell->run as administrator then run this code